# SSM always log in as Ubuntu User?

Tags: ubuntu, user-controls, aws-ssm

Is there anyway you can have a user always log in as an Ubuntu user for a ssm session instead of having to Sudo -su to Ubuntu user?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to log in with the SSM Session as another user then `ssm-user`. There is also the possibility to `su` automatically at the beginning of the session, by adding proper commands into `profile`.

In the background of the SSM Session, SSM Document is executed. You can always override the default properties of this execution (edit [Preferences](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/session-manager/preferences?region=eu-central-1) `profile`), or create a new SSM Document based on the existing one.

This is related SSM Document: `SSM-SessionManagerRunShell` [link](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/documents/SSM-SessionManagerRunShell/description?region=eu-central-1).